# Implement zero-mask to html text-input

Tags: html

I need to implement text-input in html, that:
1. user can press only digits
2. user can press max 4 digits.

Those are things that I know how to do, but I need that if user press less then 4 digits- so on lost focus - it will be completed to 4 digits by adding zero-digits at left-side as need.

How can I implement it?

Is there any way to implement all of the three requirements in on line?
May be by jquery mask?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" id="input_name">
```

This input only allows numbers in HTML5. To target this input do this:

```
var element = document.getElementByID('input_name');
```

Then add this code:

```
element.addEventListener('blur', function() {
   var elementLength = element.value.length;
   if(elementLength == 0) {
     return;
   }
   if(elementLength == 1) {
     element.value = '000'+element.value;
     return;
   }
   if(elementLength == 2) {
     element.value = '00'+element.value;
     return;
   }
   if(elementLength == 3) {
     element.value = '0'+element.value;
     return;
   }
   if(elementLength == 4) {
     return;
   }
   else {
     // Code to max the number of digits at 4
     element.value = element.value.substr(0, 3);
     return;
   }
}, false );
```

Hope this helps, Gab

Comment: It is good, but isn't there any way to implement all of the three requirements in on line?

Comment: Sadly not one that I know, sorry hope this helps though

Comment: Also I don't know why someone down voted your question by I up voted it back to 0, because I think it is a good question.

Comment: Did it work? If so give the tick so the post is classified as answered.